# Mathematical notation of "for all x in some open interval containing c except possibly at c itself""

Tags: calculus, notation, limsup-and-liminf

I am currently writing an Internal assessment about proving Squeeze Theorem, and could not find the exact notation for "for all x in some open interval containing c except possibly at c itself" It is a crucial part since the proof starts with this statement. Could anyone know the exact notation for this expression?

Comment: $\forall x\in\Bbb R:\, 0<|x-c|<\varepsilon$ for some $\varepsilon>0$.

Comment: One can say "in a deleted neighborhood of $x$".

Comment: @TitoEliatron ... except that this gives you an open interval specifically centred on $c$, rather than a general interval which contains $c$.

Comment: @PrimeMover give me a not necessarily centereed at $c$ interval, and I give you $\varepsilon>0$ satysfying my condition.

Comment: @TitoEliatron You can give me what you want, but the fact remains that the set you defined is not the set required by OP. You might want to give a full answer telling OP what you mean, in full detail.

Answer (score 0):

You could describe it as the set $S$ where $S = I \setminus \{c\}$, where $I = \{x \in \mathbb R: a < x < b\}$ where $a < c < b$.

In the above $\setminus$ means the set difference: $A \setminus B = \{x \in A: x \notin B\}$.

This of course only gives you the interval which specifically does not include $c$; I'm not sure how you would write "not necessarily including $c$".